# ASP.NET Handler for managing images/files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to do the following:

1. Show Image on a page
2. Show a link to a document (PDF, DOC etc) that opens up the document
3. Upload a image

I have the functionality in the backend that has the following signatures:

```
public byte[] GetFile(string fileName)   //For both documents and images

public void AddFile(string fileName, byte[] data)  //For both documents and images
```

My question is, can I write a handler that can get images/documents and upload images/documents so that I can use it in my client by doing a:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image.ashx?FileName=myFileName" />
```

The handler in turn would call the `GetFile` and `AddFile` methods.

This may work for showing images. What about showing documents and uploading images/documents?

Also, what about the security associated with the handler? Can a malicious user use it?

Comment: You can have the Handler stream down a Document, but you cannot upload a document through a handler.

Comment: Pretty sure it is expecting a Response not a byte[].  Need to pack the byte[] in the Response.

Comment: You can name your files with guids, that increases security because the names can't be "guessed" and you add a bool or int to branch the execution.
e.g. Image.ashx?FileName=936DA01F-9ABD-4d9d-80C7-02AF85C822A8&up=true

Comment: @CalebKeith - This is what I was looking for. Can I have a handler executing C# code which in turn does the upload?